# i had set back ground image in <a> tag and now i want to change image on mouse over event by using inline css

Tags: javascript, html, css

**this is what i'm trying.when i mouse over on that link it should change back ground image without using hover effect..**

```
 > <a href="" style="text-decoration: none;font-weight: bold;
      padding: 3px 15px 5px;background: url('image/abc.jpg') repeat-x;
      height:24px;border-radius: 4px;color: #FFF;font-size: 12px;"
      onmouseover="this.background='image/def.jpg';">change image</a>
```

**any help would be appreciated..**

Comment: Ehm... you want to do something, but not by doing it in the usual way? Why the restriction? Anyway, you should start by getting rid of all those > signs.

Comment: [Oh look, a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kkK2h/).

Comment: thanks, it was much helpful..:)

Answer (score 0):

When I mouse over a link it should change background image.
But without using a hover effect.

So you want to hover over something, because that is what you are describing, but you don't want to use a hover effect to change your background.

That is not possible.

Comment: To be honest, I think I know what the OP means: they can't use `:hover` styles for whatever reason. All they can do is set inline styles, or use event attributes.

Comment: (In that case, they are on the right track. All they need is to correct the syntax errors and to add an onmouseout...)

Comment: @Mr Lister I do think OP is trying to edit someone else's code and the hover effect is just messing things up. He should refactor his code, because you wouldn't use inline-styles anyway.

Comment: Well, I've encountered plenty situations where external stylesheets were impossible (because the user has no access to the `head`), and the only styling available was through inline style attributes

Comment: @Mr Lister What I meant was that normally you shouldn't use inline-styles and you should use an external style sheets instead. But the situation you descibed, it would be appropriate to use inline-styles since you can't use an external stylesheet.

Comment: @htmltroll i know jquery & css very well so i don't have to copy someone else's code.thanks for your reply but i have solved it using mouseover event.